# How to add String on Bitmap Image in Android?

Tags: android, bitmap, android-bitmap

I want to add a string on bitmap image.I have a metod `drawTextToBitmap`,this method working success place string on bitmap image.But my bitmap image is very small like pinmark image.This function set the string based on the bitmap height and width.I want to place the string exceed than the bitmap image.So Please help me to solve the problem.

> Following method i am using to get bitmap :

```
public Bitmap drawTextToBitmap(Context gContext, int gResId, String gText) {
    Resources resources = gContext.getResources();
    float scale = resources.getDisplayMetrics().density;
    Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(resources, gResId);

    android.graphics.Bitmap.Config bitmapConfig = bitmap.getConfig();
    // set default bitmap config if none
    if (bitmapConfig == null) {
        bitmapConfig = android.graphics.Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888;
    }
    // resource bitmaps are imutable,
    // so we need to convert it to mutable one
    bitmap = bitmap.copy(bitmapConfig, true);

    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmap);
    // new antialised Paint
    Paint paint = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
    // text color - #3D3D3D
    paint.setColor(Color.BLACK);
    // text size in pixels
    paint.setTextSize((int) (70 * scale));
    // text shadow
    paint.setShadowLayer(1f, 0f, 1f, Color.BLACK);

    // draw text to the Canvas center
    Rect bounds = new Rect();
    paint.getTextBounds(gText, 0, gText.length(), bounds);
    int m = (bitmap.getWidth() - bounds.width()) / 2;
    int l = (bitmap.getHeight() + bounds.height()) / 2;

    canvas.drawText(gText, 1000, l, paint);

    return bitmap;
}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try this:

```
public static Bitmap drawStringonBitmap(Bitmap src, String string, Point location, int color, int alpha, int size, boolean underline,int width ,int height) {

    Bitmap result = Bitmap.createBitmap(width, height, src.getConfig());

    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(result);
    canvas.drawBitmap(src, 0, 0, null);
    Paint paint = new Paint();
    paint.setColor(color);
    paint.setAlpha(alpha);
    paint.setTextSize(size);
    paint.setAntiAlias(true);
    paint.setUnderlineText(underline);
    canvas.drawText(string, location.x, location.y, paint);

    return result;
}
```